# Car Parking Management using Raspberry Pi

Tags: wifi, server

How can I create a car parking system using Raspberry Pi.

I need to do it for 5-8 car parking slots. If the slot is empty I need to send the data to my server.

Which sensor should I use and Suggest me a guide to connect Raspberry Pi to Wifi device and send it to the cloud.

Answer (score 2):

how about an ultrasonic distance measurer for each space.

[this guide should help](https://www.modmypi.com/blog/hc-sr04-ultrasonic-range-sensor-on-the-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score 0):

If you can put a pi with camera above parking, you can use **[OpenCV](http://www.opencv.org)** library to find out free parking slots. Beware, this is not a project for beginner and requests intensive development work.